# Creating Netcdf files issue

Tags: r

I have created some netcdf files in R before, but right now, I am having some problems to create a netcdf file that I don't know how handle it. I have been looking for the error but I am not sure why it is. Given that my data is too long, I include a smaller sample to give an idea about the structure:

```
     #data.frame with the date and the values
      dat <-dput(y.or[1:10,])
      structure(list(date = structure(c(852073200, 852159600, 852246000, 
      852332400, 852418800, 852505200, 852591600, 852678000, 852764400, 
      852850800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), dymax = c(79.125, 
      75.375, 78, 72.375, 76.375, 76.571, 76.125, 82.75, 86.125, 86
      )), .Names = c("date", "dymax"), row.names = c("1997-01-01.01", 
      "1997-01-01.02", "1997-01-01.03", "1997-01-01.04", "1997-01-01.05", 
      "1997-01-01.06", "1997-01-01.07", "1997-01-01.08", "1997-01-01.09", 
      "1997-01-01.10"), class = "data.frame")

     #****Creating Netcdf files********
      #One lat and lon, and 5478 days (14 years)
      missval  <- -999
      dimX <- dim.def.ncdf( "longitude", "degrees_east",10)
      dimY <- dim.def.ncdf( "latitude", "degrees_north", 50)
      dimT  <- dim.def.ncdf("time",as.Date(dates[1]),as.numeric(dates))

      #Def.variable
       var <- var.def.ncdf(name="max8hO3","ppb",list(dimX,dimY,dimT), missval=missval,            longname="max8hO3",prec="double")
      #creating the file
      fil <- create.ncdf("fileout.nc",var)
```

Then, before put the variable into the file , I have:

```
      Error in nc$var[[nc$varid2Rindex[varid]]] : 
      attempt to select less than one element
```

I am sure that I am missing something...but I don't know, any idea???
I really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: There are some errors in your code: what is `y.or`? What is `dates`? If I just use the data structure and change `dimT` to `dimT  <- dim.def.ncdf("time",'days',dat$date)`, everything seems alright.

Comment: What a bug!I had not realised about that a but, thanks  a lot for the help!